# How do I add the like facebook button to a silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I'm new to silverlight 4 development. 
I need the facebook I like button to be integrated integrated on my website application?
Can someone tell me how to do that?

Can I download a library that will provide me a user control that is visible in my toolbox, and thus I will be able to just drag and drop this item on my page?
If not, how can I implement this functionality?

Comment: @the_drow: Please keep in mind that many of the people posting here do not have English as their first language. Please avoid making rude comments about that fact, and be more tolerant instead. You've been here long enough to have done so, but perhaps you should review the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about being respectful and polite to others. That philosophy is part of what allows SO to work as well as it does. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite: I apologize if I came off rude. Us programmers don't often have people skills. My intention is to be constructive and helpful, if everyone would work to improve their English, all of the questions will be much more comprehensible and thus as a result, they will have much more useful answers. English is not my first language as well, and yet I learned.

Comment: I certainly was not angry on the response off "the_drow"! Thanks for your help anyway. And I try to improve my English ;) ! (native language is Dutch, i'm from Belgium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just download a like button image from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and use the [Facebook SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) to like the page.
I haven't tried it myself but it should be possible.
Another approach will be to use the Javascript API and call it from silverlight.
Here's how: http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/Silverlight-Tutorial-321.aspx
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/silverlight-and-javascript-interaction
http://www.mostlydevelopers.com/blog/post/2008/08/11/Call-Javascript-Method-from-Silverlight-and-Vice-Versa.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke the "I like" feature from silverlight you can just call javascript code (rise the onclick event) from silverlight which located on your page.

Comment: Yes, sorry! I updated the question. It's indeed the facebook 'I like' button.

Comment: Compiler: Please do not include clarification requests on answers in the future. Use the comments. They exist for a reason.