# Facebook like button with silverlight

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, facebook, silverlight

I have created a silverlight app that consits of like buttons within specific usercontrols (all in one asp page). Ie.

foodingtons.net/index.aspx?id=211

It is all incorporated within the silverlight app on one page. Hence when the control is loaded the meta tags are updated and the like button is placed within an iframe and linked to the appropriate page. When the like button is pressed a javascript function is invoked which changes a picture behind the silverlight obj. This picture in theory should be used as the default image after the like button is pressed (on clients page). But it seems to be stuck on old images. 
Ie. 
foodingtons.net/index.aspx?id=211
(the above is using an image which doesnt even exist)

foodingtons.net/index.aspx?id=218
(is using an image from the main page)

foodingtons.net/index.aspx?id=219
(fails.. the website is inaccessable)

I have also tried create the open graph tags with in the page to reference new images but to no avail.

I'm using the following facebook tool to debug as well
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

a bit lost ... any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add the like facebook button to a silverlight application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213077/how-do-i-add-the-like-facebook-button-to-a-silverlight-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out what was going on. Facebook and google (using their bots) cannot crawl into the silvelright control itself. So they cannot invoke the functions that will get the meta and pics changing. Had to call the change meta stuff from the asp page itself. All sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Add Facebook Like to your Silverlight Application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/Blogs/SilverlightFacebookLike.aspx).

Comment: Hi Ekk Im using that paticular tutorial to create the like button. But it isnt a question of how to add a like button; its more a question of why isnt the right pic being associated to the page or even why no pic is being associated at all.

Im a bit lost here. Any suggestions?